# How to save a list of words and the positions of these words in the sentence as separate files or as a single file?

Tags: python

This  is what i have so far for the first part of the task where i have to make a programme that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word in the original sentence with the position of that word in the list:

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence?: ")
sentence_split = sentence.split() 
sentence2 = [0]
print(sentence)
for count, i in enumerate(sentence_split): 
    if sentence_split.count(i) < 2:
        sentence2.append(max(sentence2) + 1)
    else:
        sentence2.append(sentence_split.index(i) +1)
sentence2.remove(0)
print(sentence2)
```

This above code works fine i just need help with the part of the task that is in the title cause i am completely stuck.

Comment: I am not totally sure what you're asking about. Do you need help printing to files?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what I'm asking. The task states i need to save the sentence into a single or separate file but i have no clue what this means. My teacher has refused to help and said that we should use 'research skills' to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to do something like this?

```
sentence = raw_input("What is your sentence?: ")
sentence_lst = [a for a in sentence.split()]

sentence2 = dict(enumerate(sentence_lst))
print "sentence2 =",sentence2
```

Once you have position of each word, you can replace as per your needs.

**Output:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
What is your sentence?: hi there how are you
sentence2 = {0: 'hi', 1: 'there', 2: 'how', 3: 'are', 4: 'you'}
>>>
```

Comment: urrrm no, not at all